# Ошибка 0xc000007b во время запуска mongod.exe / mongo.exe

Tags: windows, mongodb

Всем привет!

Установил [mongodb](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=docs&_ga=1.266214607.1512492728.1490195057#community) на Windows.

**Mongodb**: 3.4.3 - Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit, with SSL support x64

**OS**: Windows 7 64-bit

Когда запускаю **mongod.exe** или **mongo.exe** возникает ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я только не делал, чтобы решить эту ошибку: обновлял драйвера для видео-карты, запускал разные утилиты, которые чинят регистр и системные файлы, обновлял Net Framework, но ничего не помогло.

Если кто-то встречался с подобной проблемой или знает как это решить, помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Comment: Запускал от имени "Администратора"?

Comment: Да, не помогает(

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же ошибка, помогла переустановка mongodb другой версии (их там 3 штуки, я выбрал самую простую MongoDB for Windows 64-bit Legacy). Перезагрузил компьютер после установки и все заработало, было даже неожиданно

Answer (score 0):

После того как обновил Visual C++ Redistributable, всё заработало. Не знаю была ли проблема только в этом, т.к. до этого обновил и Net Framework и DirectX и дрова для видео-карты, но тем не менее, после обновления Visual C++ Redistributable всё заработало.